# Images having the same percentage height and width are rendering with different heights

Tags: html, css

I've been reading in multiple places that if you measure images in percentage, that the percentage is based on its parent container. Given the following code, I cannot understand why two different images, given the same height and width percentage would yield two slightly different size outputs.

```css
div {
  border: solid black;
}
img {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="../images/458.jpg">
  <img src="../images/650S.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The images are being sized based on the `width: 40%` only.

Your `height: 40%` is being ignored, because the parent element doesn't have a height specified.

In a block formatting context, a height *must* be declared on the parent for a percentage height to work on the child, unless the child is absolutely positioned.

See here for details: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Try this:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
div {
  height: 100%;
  border: solid black;
}
img {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="../images/458.jpg">
  <img src="../images/650S.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

They are gives you different output because of your parent `div`. You did not assign to it any sizes: `width` of `height`. Therefore, browser using original sizes to calculate new sizes.

If you will add something like this to your style:

```
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

The output should be the same.